# how to make this program using switch case instead of if else. basic coding please, im only in 9th grade

Tags: bluej

so im supposed to make this program, except i have to use switch case. i searched my book, tried it and cant understand. how do i use it to input different values for StudentGrade

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class IfGrades
{ 
    public static void main()
   {
      /** establishing variables*/

        String StudentName, StudentClass;
        char StudentGrade;
        int Marks1, Marks2, Marks3, Marks4, Marks5;
        double TotalMarks, Percentage;

       /**Inputting values for variables*/

        Scanner stringy = new Scanner (System.in);

        //Name code
        System.out.println("Enter the Student Name: ");
        StudentName = stringy.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the class and division: ");
        StudentClass = stringy.nextLine();

        //Marks and Grade code

        Scanner marks = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter marks for 5 subjects out of 100: ");
        Marks1 = marks.nextInt();
        Marks2 = marks.nextInt();
        Marks3 = marks.nextInt();
        Marks4 = marks.nextInt();
        Marks5 = marks.nextInt();

        TotalMarks = Marks1 + Marks2 + Marks3 + Marks4 + Marks5;

        Percentage = (TotalMarks/500) * 100;

        if (Percentage >=90)
        {
        StudentGrade = 'A';
        }
         else if ((Percentage >= 70) && (Percentage < 90))
        {
            StudentGrade = 'B';
        }
        else if ((Percentage >= 50) && (Percentage < 70))
        {
            StudentGrade = 'C';
        }
        else if ((Percentage >= 40) && (Percentage < 50))
        {
            StudentGrade = 'D';
        }
        else 
        {
            StudentGrade = 'E';
        }

        /** Outputting Values */

        System.out.println("Student name is " +StudentName);

        System.out.println("Student class is " +StudentClass);

        System.out.println("Total marks scored by student are " +TotalMarks);

        System.out.println("Percentage scored by student is " +Percentage);

        System.out.println("Grade of Student is " +StudentGrade);
    }
}
```

i tried using "switch ((int)Percentage >= 90) but it doesnt let me put it in the StudentGrade value

can anyone help me making this in switch case? the part between dashes

Comment: `Percentage = (TotalMarks/500) * 100` looks like integer division gone wrong. You should probably use `Percentage = (TotalMarks * 100) / 500` or just `Percentage = TotalMarks / 5`, optionally extract constants.

Comment: @Magma ok i understood the first part, but what do you mean by "extracting constants"

Comment: Instead of writing `Percentage = (TotalMarks * 100) / 500`, you could write `Percentage = (TotalMarks * MAX_PERCENTAGE) / MAX_POINTS`, where `MAX_PERCENTAGE` and `MAX_POINTS` are constant variables you introduced earlier.

Comment: Also I don't think that using a switch statement here is a good idea, you'd need either dozens of cases or obfuscating mathematics. Why do you want a switch statement?